# Repeat Array within single JSON object (Ioinc 2)

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, ionic-framework

I have a JSON object that has an array of ingredients within, I want to repeat each object into an `<li>` so I can list them out. The area I want to repeat is the "ingredientLines"

My JSON is[image]

My current code is, I currently just get all 10 objects listed out in a single `<li>`

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <div class="thumb">
                <ion-img src="{{api?.images["0"].hostedLargeUrl}}">
                <h1>{{api?.name}}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="action-bar">
                <div class="like">
                </div>
                <div class="time">
                    <span>{{api?.totalTime}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="share">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredients" ng-repeat="items in api">
                <ul>
                    <li>{{api?.ingredientLines}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

If someone could point out where I'm going wrong that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to repeat the right object in the right HTML-Element and you will be fine. Here is a [abstract working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvpf64h8/) of what you try to achieve.

```
<div class="ingredients">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of api?.ingredientLines">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oww, its Angular instead of AngularJS. That wasnt clear.

Comment: Sorry my bad! :) Thankyou though!